# filter out double value sql in top3 search

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have an sql code. this works fine, only if the third and fourth score is the same. than it will keep all four scores. but I want only three.

```
SELECT t.Stamboomnr, t.Score, t.Trail, t.Time, t.Place, t.Quali, t.Division, t.StockKlasID
FROM Tbl09_Stock AS t
WHERE (((t.Score) In (SELECT TOP 3  t1.Score FROM [Tbl09_Stock] AS t1 where t1.Stamboomnr = t.Stamboomnr order by t1.Score desc)))
ORDER BY t.Stamboomnr, t.Score DESC;
```

i have tried to put DISTINCT just in front of TOP3 that didn't work.

thanks Allard

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```sql
SELECT t.Stamboomnr, t.Score, t.Trail, t.Time, t.Place, t.Quali, t.Division, t.StockKlasID
FROM Tbl09_Stock AS t
WHERE t.Score In 
(SELECT DISTINCT t2.Score From
    (SELECT TOP 3 t1.Score 
    FROM [Tbl09_Stock] AS t1 
    where t1.Stamboomnr = t.Stamboomnr order by t1.Score desc) As t2) 
ORDER BY t.Stamboomnr, t.Score DESC;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. but i get a error t.Stamboomnr he can't find. and you get a reduced selection of only 3 records.

Comment: It would be nice with some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

| Stamboomnr | Score | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E140581 | 95 | 1199 |
| E140581 | 90 | 1111 |
| E140581 | 77 | 1100 |
| E163988 | 115 | 2345 |
| E163988 | 110 | 2345 |
| E163988 | 99 | 2345 |
| E172856 | 110 | 1231 |
| E172856 | 100 | 1234 |
| E172856 | 99 | 2345 |
| E172856 | 99 | 1234 |
| E178963 | 125 | 2233 |
| E178963 | 122 | 1111 |
| E178963 | 110 | 1010 |

FOR E1722856 is de sql not working the rest ar great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to rebuild the SQL

```
SELECT t.Stamboomnr, t.Score, t.Time, t.Trail, t.Place, t.Quali, t.Division, t.StockKlasID, Tbl03_Dogs.ArmnumberStock
FROM Tbl03_Dogs INNER JOIN Tbl09_Stock AS t ON Tbl03_Dogs.Stamboomnr = t.Stamboomnr
WHERE (((t.Score) In (SELECT  top 3 [Score] from [Tbl09_Stock] as t1 where t1.Stamboomnr = t.Stamboomnr and t1.score <> (SELECT  Min(Score) AS MinOfScore FROM  Tbl09_Stock AS Dupe      
   WHERE (Dupe.Stamboomnr = t.Stamboomnr) AND (Dupe.Time > t.Time)  ) order by t1.Score Desc)))
ORDER BY t.Stamboomnr, t.Score DESC , t.Time;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t.Stamboomnr, t.Score, t.Time, t.Trail, t.Place, t.Quali, t.Division, t.StockKlasID INTO Tbl_HCCount
FROM Tbl09_Stock AS t
WHERE (((t.Quali)="Q") AND ((Format([Score],"0000") & Format([Time],"0000")) In (SELECT  top 3  Format(Score,"0000") & Format(Time,"0000") FROM [Tbl09_Stock] AS t1 WHERE t1.Stamboomnr = t.Stamboomnr ORDER BY  Format(Score,"0000") & Format(Time,"0000") DESC)))
ORDER BY t.Stamboomnr, Format(Score,"0000") & Format(Time,"0000") DESC;

this is working

Comment: Lacks formatting